# Proxy authentication and then Web client authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication

Having an issue with proxy authentications.

Basically, the problem arose from customers trying to connect to our server application using a proxy resulted in a 407 error. This was fixed easily by adding

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
  </system.net>
```

to the app.config, as has been discussed in many other questions on stack overflow.

My problem is that our client application has it's own authentication process through web client that authenticates our server app database. Because I have set the client to use defaultCredentials if we are going through a proxy, the application is trying to log onto our server app using the default credentials (e.g. MyWindowsDomain\MyWindowsUser1), which obviously gives an invalid login as this user does not exist in the server app user database. Anyone run into this problem before and know how to fix it? Or any ideas?